# javascript code for googleplus

Tags: javascript

can anyone see if there is something missing from this javascript please?

```
function john() {
  var w = 480;
  var h = 380;
  var x = Number((window.screen.width - w) / 2);
  var y = Number((window.screen.height - h) / 2);
  window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href) + ' & title = '+encodeURIComponent(document.title),'
      ','
      width = '+w+', height = '+h+', left = '+x+', top = '+y    +',
      scrollbars = no ');
```

I am working on a google plus sharing code for a Muse website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function john()
{
var w=480;var h=380;
var x=Number((window.screen.width-w)/2);
var y=Number((window.screen.height-h)/2);
window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(document.title),'','width='+w+',height='+h+',left='+x+',top='+y    +',  scrollbars=no');
}
```

**1.** You are missing the end Brace '}' in your code.

**2.** Do not split your code statement across multiple lines as Javascript can do automatic semi colon insertion. In case, if you need to split the string across multiple lines then you can make use of **backticks** ``.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a syntax error in your example. Here is code that works:

JSFiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/x0qo41ok/

```
function john() {
  var w = 480;
  var h = 380;
  var x = Number((window.screen.width - w) / 2);
  var y = Number((window.screen.height - h) / 2);
  window.open(
    "https://plus.google.com/share?url=" +
    encodeURIComponent(location.href) + 
    "&title=" + 
    encodeURIComponent(document.title),
    "",
    "width=" + w +",height=" + h + ",left=" + x + ",top=" + y +",resizable=yes"
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! thats a great help - now to get the links working in IE and I will be happy :)